# Mixing two RAM with different CAS Latency / Timing

Tags: memory, desktop

I already have :
8GB + 8GB RAM  with 3200MHZ / CL16 / Timing 16-18-18

I want to add :
8GB + 8GB RAM with with 3200MHZ / CL16 / Timing 16-20-20

The different is with the timing which
16-18-18 and 16-20-20

is it will cause problem with mixing the Timing?

Answer (score 2):

Not anymore.

It used to be a problem, but motherboards got a lot better and will simply run at the slowest speed (bigger number = slower; in this case 16-20-20). Your faster RAM will simply be running at the slow RAM's speed.