# Mixing different RAM MHz and CAS latency

Tags: memory, cpu, performance

Is it possible to mix different rams with different CAS latency and different MHz?

Such as mixing 16 GB cl 17 2933 MHz DDR4 and 16 GB cl 20 3200 MHz DDR4 for the laptop for the which CPU supports max 2933 MHz. My goal here is to achieve dual-channel 32 GB ram instead of single-channel 16 GB ram.

I do know that system will run the ram with lowest MHz, I'm only concerned that will it be a dual-channel?

Comment: Your over thinking things.  The performance differences between those two modules won’t be noticed outside a benchmark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing two RAM with different CAS Latency / Timing](https://superuser.com/questions/1605170/mixing-two-ram-with-different-cas-latency-timing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing RAM sticks with different CAS Latency and timings?](https://superuser.com/questions/1226768/mixing-ram-sticks-with-different-cas-latency-and-timings)

Answer (score 1):

Dualchanellness depends solely on your CPU and motherboard, it is not affected by exact memory specs as long as your RAM sticks are compatible and are of the same size (there're configurations when it's possible to get dualchannel on different sized sticks, but involves more trickery and is not always possible).

When combining different specced ram - it will run at lowest speed supported by all involved hardware (unless you overclock).